#  Find matrix $A$ of $f$ with respect to the standard bases of $V$ and $W$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $V=\Bbb{R}^3$ and $W=\Bbb{R}^2$.

Let $f:V\to W$ such that $f(x,y,z)=(zx+z,3y)$.

Find matrix $A$ of $f$ with respect to the standard bases of $V$ and $W$?

Comment: @DavidMitra Then we would have $f\colon V \to V$ ... perhaps the answer should read "As $f$ isn't linear, it cannot be represented by a matrix."

Comment: @martini Yes. Comment deleted. What could $f$ be?

Answer (score 1):

As Martini already commented, $f$ cannot be represented by a matrix as it is *not* a linear map between $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^2$.

So either you choose this as your answer to your question or else check the question carefully to verify the given $f$ is what you gave.

*Quick proof of non-linearity:* $$f(1,1,1)=(2,3)$$$$f(2,2,2)=(6,6)\neq (4,6)=2f(1,1,1)$$